# converting dictionary to dataframe column in pandas

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a nested dictionary like this

```
  d = {1 : {'we': 26, 'is': 112},
       2 : {'tp': 26, 'fp': 91},
       3 : {'pp': 23, 'kj': 74}}
```

I want to change it to a dataframe column such that outer dict keys become rows  and its element act as an element of the column.

Desired Output:

```
  rows           col1      
  1      'we': 26, 'is': 112
  2      'tp': 26, 'fp': 91
  3      'pp': 23, 'kj': 74
```

Comment: convert the dict to json

Comment: I am rather new to Python. Have not used json and pickle yet,But comfortable with pandas and numpy.

Comment: Why use pandas for this data structure, rather than just keeping the vanilla python dict?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If that's what you have in your dictionary, it isn't necessarily going to preserve the order of the keys for the inner dict.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {1 : {'we': 26, 'is': 112},
     2 : {'tp': 26, 'fp': 91},
     3 : {'pp': 23, 'kj': 74}}
# Replace the inner dicts with their string representations
for i in d:
    d[i] = str(d[i])
# Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index()
# Clean up column names
df.rename(columns={'index': 'row', 0: 'col1'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can this method be applied to a list  also ?

Comment: @PrashantSharma you can certainly create a dataframe from lists, but I don't really have enough context to explain, please create a new question with examples / code if needed

Comment: I successfully did that with list also. Thanks a lot for your response!!